# How to add worker thread in Electron JS?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

How do we add worker thread in Electron JS?
I have tried below which works fine in dev mode.

```
const worker = new Worker(path.join(__dirname, 'worker.js'));
```

But this causes error when the app is packaged, it is looking for worker.js inside app.asar. Even with the worker.js included in build/files.

Comment: 8 months ago, did you found a way to that?

Comment: No, I ended up using multiple renderer process as workers.

Comment: my solution was to unpack the workers but I can't require my modules, only node native modules.
I also tried the cluster module, but it forks the entire electron process and causes bugs.
May you can share your technic ?

Comment: I required only 2 workers, so I just created 2 more renderer process without any UI, it was also easier to interact with the renderer process since we could use electron's IPC modules.

Comment: I know this has been posted more than two years ago, but how did you communicate between the two render processes? I am currently facing your exact issue at the moment.

Comment: Hey, I actually have the same problem. Is there any solution available?

Comment: @Wokers I've added an answer I think may help you.

Comment: See also similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/59254016/254109

Answer (score 1):

I actually have found the answer on Webpack documentation.

```
new Worker(new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url));
```

and it worked for me. https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am getting Worker is not define. Using electron forge 6 and electron 25.5.0

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do a patch like this instead of using `__dirname`, because `__dirname` will resolve to the ASAR when in production, as you have found:

```js
const { app } = require('electron');

const rootPath = app.isPackaged ? app.getAppPath() : __dirname;
const worker = new Worker(path.join(rootPath, 'worker.js'));
```

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appispackaged-readonly

Note that based on your exact setup you may need to navigate up or down a folder in your production app, in which case you can use something like:

```js
const rootPath = app.isPackaged ? app.getAppPath() : path.join(__dirname, '..');
```